# Script which replaces specific words in text by asterisks (Python)

Tags: python

I tried to create a function which finds a censored word (which is an argument of the function)  in a text (which is a second argument) and replaces all the instances of the word with astrerisks.

```
def censor(text, word):
    if word in text:
        position = text.index(word)
        new_text = text[0: position] + "*"*len(word) + text[position+len(word):]
        censor(new_text,word)
    else:
        return text


phrase_with = raw_input("Type the sentence")
foo= raw_input("Type the censored word")
print censor(phrase_with, foo)
```

But when I call the function inside the function itself it stops working.

And returns "**None**". Why? How can I make it work?

And what are the rules of callling a function within the same function?

Comment: Not the most efficient code. `def censor(text, word): return ("*"*4).join(text.split(word))` will do.

Comment: Yeah! I understand. But given that I'm on my 3rd day of learning Python I'm more than happy with mine. Yours looks cryptic for me so far. But thank you!

Comment: This is not remotely a job for recursion. Also try to keep the profanity out of your questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to return the recursive result like this:

```
def censor(text, word):
    if word in text:
        position = text.index(word)
        new_text = text[0: position] + "*"*len(word) + text[position+len(word):]
        return censor(new_text,word) # <-- Add return here
    else:
        return text


phrase_with_fuck = raw_input("Type the sentence")
fuck = raw_input("Type the censored word")
print censor(phrase_with_fuck, fuck)
```

This happens because the function ends in the `if` statement, resulting None.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Giordano!